# Removing left recursion(Убрать левую рекурсию)

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, рекурсия, компилятор, antlr

После обработки грамматики VHDL ANTLRом мне нужно допилить полученный синтаксичесий анализатор, а именно избавиться от left recursion.Никак не могу понять, как же мне её пофиксить. В интернете не смог найти вменяемых примеров именно с кодом, алгоритм фикса понимаю, но чёт никак не могу его применить.
Мною был добавлен `own_name_aux`, что делать дальше не понимаю.

```
 own_name ::=
   simple_name own_name_aux
 | operator_symbol own_name_aux
 | CHARACTER_LITERAL own_name_aux
 | selected_name own_name_aux
 | indexed_name own_name_aux
 | slice_name own_name_aux
 | attribute_name own_name_aux
 | external_name own_name_aux

own_name_aux ::=
 /*empty*/
 | '.' suffix

prefix ::= function_call | own_name 

suffix ::=
   simple_name
 | CHARACTER_LITERAL
 | operator_symbol
 | 'all'

 function_call ::=
  /*function_*/own_name ('(' actual_parameter_part ')')?
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, от рекурсии избавляются добавлением простого синтаксического предиката перед вызовом проблемного правила. Это может быть банальный бектрек на одну лексему вперед, просто, чтобы убедиться, нужно ли продолжать рекурсию.

Из кода так навскидку рекурсии не вижу. Разве что вот правило simple_name вызывается рекурсивно. Если еще актуально, приведите конкретный код ошибки с указанием строки и позиции.